# What is a valid URI in SPARQL?

Tags: uri, sparql

Both SPARQL and Turtle define `IRIREF` as a production of `<` and `>` not containing one of the invalid characters and refer to [RDF 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for details. The URI reference syntax element either denotes an (absolute) URI or a relative reference if it cannot be parsed as an absolute URI.

This makes me believe that `urn,:` is a relative reference, since it doesn't begin with a valid scheme. However, writing this into a [validator](http://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html):

```
SELECT ?a
WHERE {
  BIND(<urn,:> as ?a)
}
```

Fails:

> [line: 3, col: 8 ] Bad IRI: 'urn,:':  Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in SCHEME: The character violates the grammar rules for URIs/IRIs.

Why? Is it according to the specification or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator is correct here. The problem is that you have a ':' at the end of what would be the first segment of your relative path. To quote [section 4.2 of RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2):

> A path segment that contains a colon character (e.g., "this:that")
> cannot be used as the first segment of a relative-path reference, as
> it would be mistaken for a scheme name.  Such a segment must be
> preceded by a dot-segment (e.g., "./this:that") to make a relative-
> path reference.

In the ABNF this is expressed by the fact that for a relative path there is this production:

```
      relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty
                    / path-absolute
                    / path-noscheme
                    / path-empty
```

Since your URI doesn't start with a '/' and is not empty, only `path-noscheme` potentially matches:

```
path-noscheme = segment-nz-nc *( "/" segment )
```

The `segment-nz-nc` rule is explicitly there to rule out the use of a colon in the first element of the path:

```
  segment-nz-nc = 1*( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / "@" )
                 ; non-zero-length segment without any colon ":"
```

Comment: That explains why the only characters that would be valid instead of `,` are `/`, `?` and `#`, since they end the `segment-nz-nc`. I assumed "this:that" meant only letters or other characters that would be valid in a scheme, but it seems the ABNF rules it out. Thanks!